# VC++: How to capture the Events fired from an ActiveX (.ocx) inside ATL project

Tags: c++, activex, atl, ocx

I am making an wrapper of a control, an interface of the ocx object. Had to create an ATL project and then add/load the ocx file. It has exposed properties, methods and events. I am able to control/used its properties and methods however I was stuck on events, especially handling it after it fires.

Have searched it on google and most of the guides I've found are making it from scratch or from the ATL events itself. What I am trying to achieve is to make use of the exposed events from the ocx. Any have idea?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In ATL your standard options to handle COM events is to use `IConnectionPointContainer` and friends as explained in [Event Handling and ATL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk9be55d.aspx):

> For information on how to fire events and implement connection points, read [ATL Connection Points](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7kad5hw.aspx).

Or, and especially for ActiveX control events, your second option is `IDispEventImpl` class references there by the first link as well:

- [Using IDispEventImpl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06wtz4t5.aspx), inlcuding sample referenced
- [AtlEvnt.exe sample shows how to creates ATL sinks by using the ATL `IDispEventImpl` and `IDispEventSimpleImpl` classes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/194179/atlevnt.exe-sample-shows-how-to-creates-atl-sinks-by-using-the-atl-idispeventimpl-and-idispeventsimpleimpl-classes)

`IDispEventImpl` is explained in detail on other resources too, e.g.:

- [Understanding COM Event Handling](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9014/Understanding-COM-Event-Handling) on CodeProject